# WordPress with SQLite Integration Plugin

Tags: linux, wordpress, sqlite, ubuntu, pdo

just downloaded wordpress-4.1.2.zip and sqlite-integration.1.8.1.zip and unzipped them locally in a system with the following specifications:

- Apache: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- PHP: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
- php5-sqlite: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9

I stored sqlite-integration folder in plugins folder, and moved db.php file to wp-content folder and generated the required keys...
The result was this message:

> PDO Driver for SQLite is missing.
>   Your PHP installtion appears not to
>   have the right PDO drivers loaded. These are required for this version
>   of WordPress and the type of database you have specified.

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your host does not have PDO extension enabled in php.ini, please do enable them to avoid this error.

check this link to see how you can enable the extension:

http://php.net/manual/it/pdo.installation.php

On unix based systems if you don't have ssh access you should remove ; in php.ini before :

```
;extension=pdo.so
```

to

```
extension=pdo.so
```

if you didn't find the above lines in php.ini add them and remember to restart your server.

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

or follow the terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql
```

else you can follow the answer of @christian-nguyen

Comment: You mean `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file? I didn't find `;extension=pdo.so`, so where should I put it? under `[sqlite]`, `[sqlite3]`, or `[pdo]`?

Comment: yes , you have to enable it in php.ini . do it if you don't have ssh / terminal access for server , else you can follow Christian's answer with : sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite

Comment: I'm doing every thing locally, no remote server.

Comment: @AnasR. if you didn't find them add them :  `extension=pdo.so`,
`extension=pdo_mysql.so` check my updated answer

Comment: @AnasR. check my edit in asnwer and add them in php.ini add them under : [pdo]

Comment: It returned: _Unable to create the required directory! Please check your server settings._

Comment: @AnasR. check my answer's new edit. and please clear me if pdo works now and you having another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just install php5-sqlite:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Comment: I did; it wasn't enough.